# if else statement on dataframe obtained by csv in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, switch-statement

I have uploded two csv files through `read.csv`

First dataframe as `dos_log`

[image: First dataframe as dos_log]

Second Csv file as `net_pay`

[image: Second Csv file as net_pay]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqLkU.png): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxyXm.png)

I want to do
1) Take  each `psno` and `new_log_value` from `dos_log`

> (let say for `PSNo` - 2011421  ,  `Log_new_value`  - 12-Jun-2017)

2) Then compare it with `Trans_month` in `net_pay`(in `net_pay` first select same `psno` as in `dos_log` , then see in `trans_month` that it value should be zero as compare with `log_new_value`

> eg For `psno` (20114241) `log_new_value` is  12-jun-2017 
>   then we will see in `net_pay` that `trans_month` value should be zero after Jun & if not count

3) Then stored this result in another dataframe

Comment: Please add a sample of how your output must look like

Comment: @trollster  plz look

Comment: You need to align the date formats using `strptime` / `strftime`. Then a simple `ifelse` statement can make the comparison

Comment: Please use `dput` to include a sample of your data in the question